# Can't turn on wifi on Mac OSX Mountain lion MBP 2012

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, wifi

The WiFi interface won't turn on when i press "Activate wifi" from the preferences neither from the status bar.

I tried restarting the mac,and reset the pram.

The Ethernet works fine and this is the result of ifconfig in the terminal:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 options=2b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,TSO4> ether a8:20:66:37:81:d9  inet6 fe80::aa20:66ff:fe37:81d9%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4  inet
192.168.1.131 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255 media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control>) status: active

en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 ether 5c:96:9d:89:fe:09  media: autoselect (<unknown type>) status: inactive
```

Is there anything I can try before initialize OSX?

Comment: You mean the lock icon in the bottom left corner? Yes, it's unlocked...

Comment: What is the syntax? "-bash: Airport: command not found"

Comment: Got it: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I
AirPort: Off

Not so useful indeed! :D

Comment: Uhm.. it's not done.. my wifi is still off! The airport command told me: AirPort: Off

Comment: "sudo ifconfig en1 up"    to turn it on! it will ask you for password.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work..

Comment: Try an hard switch off. It worked for me some time ago. Hold down the power switch for 5 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted some of my comments, since I think to now understand your question. How to turn on BOTH network interfaces on at same time! If this is not what you trying to do, then just turn off the Ethernet (or unplug it) to make the WiFi work.

Comment: → Lolloz89: if you still exist, please remove answer to old comments.

Comment: Your Wi-Fi interface is `en`. From the output of your command `ifconfig` this interface is up and running. But in fact since your Ethernet interface is also up and running (`UP`, `RUNNING` flags) your problem may be that you aren't using the interface you want. This is a common nightmare with the infamous `Automatic` network configuration.

Answer (score 8):

Cycling the network setup has worked for me. Run the following in Terminal:

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. What does this actually do?

Answer (score 2):

Found [this](http://dioisme.blogspot.com/2012/05/solving-wifi-wont-turn-on-lion-osx.html):

- Restart your mac.
- Open "Network Preferences". On the left tab, look for wifi connection (usually named Wi-Fi).
- Select the wifi connection, and disable that. To disable a connection, choose gear icon below the tab, and choose "Make Service Inactive".
- After disabled, delete the connection. To delete a connection, choose minus (-) icon below the tab, left of gear icon.
- Now that the original connection has been deleted, we must create a new wifi connection. Choose plus (+) icon, select "Wi-Fi" as interface, and you can name it anything as you want, it doesn't matter thought.
- Apply the change. Once again, restart your mac.
- After system reboot, voila ! your wifi should be working properly by now

Comment: This also worked on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) with Mojave - cycling the power did not work. It's important to disable connection before deleting.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you perform the following steps to cycle the power to your wireless card:

1. Open the Terminal application (/Applications/Utilities).
2. Enter the following text (easier to copy and paste):
   `networksetup -setairportpower en0 off; networksetup -setairportpower en0 on`
3. This should cycle the power to your wireless card, and hopefully give it the push it needs to resume normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Plug in the MagSafe Power adapter to a power source, connecting it to the Mac if it is not already connected.
3. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
4. Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
5. Press the power button to turn on your computer.