# MacBook Pro unable to turn WiFi on

Tags: network, wifi, hardware

Macbook Pro Mid 2012. The problem was there before upgrade, but recently upgraded to Mojave ( thought it might fix it )

I suspect a bad WiFi card, but the symptoms are very strange, and does not indicate the "Hardware Not Found" error.

• On Boot, WiFi works great, but will shut off anywhere from 30 minutes to 3 hours.

•The WiFi states that it is OFF, and I cannot turn it on via restarting the wireless service via command line or System preferences. Pressing the "Turn Wi-Fi On" button does nothing. The only way to fix is a power off and power on.

[image]

•The same problem has occurred on both recovery OS, a system update, and a fresh install ( booted off a different hard drive with a fresh install of MAC), so I have confirmed not a software issue.

•The WiFi Diagnostics tool has not returned anything useful except something along the lines of "enable WiFi and connect to a WiFi network".

•Resetted SMC / PRAM, still have issue

•The well-known typical "hardware not found" message has rarely shown up, I may have seen this happen once, but it is usually the strange problem with WiFi not being able to turn on, not a hardware error message.

EDIT:
During Down times, here is what is shown under the WiFi menu on about this Mac:
[image]

When the Wi-Fi is working, here is what it shows:
[image]

The only difference is the Country code is set to "X0" whenever it is not working, but was pointed out that I need to connect to network for country code to be found.

**EDIT: Output of**

```
log show --predicate '(processImagePath contains "kernel") && (eventMessage contains "AirPort: Link Down")' --style syslog --last 1d
```

[image]

What are the next steps I can take to diagnose this problem?

Comment: during the down times, what does it show in About this Mac > WiFi ? also are you on some kind managed Mac, or Parental control ? Did you try to log in as different user ?

Comment: I added a screenshot of what it shows.

Comment: thanks, so the hardware is all there but something has tuned it off.

Comment: OK, lets run `log show --predicate '(processImagePath contains "kernel") && (eventMessage contains "AirPort: Link Down") --style syslog --last 1d` to show why it was down for last 24 hours

Comment: also try to tun it on with `sudo ifconfig en1 up`
`

Comment: "sudo ifconfig en1 up" does not work. And the log command you gave hangs with > symbol, and if I add a quote, it gives me "bad predicate error"

Comment: I just tired it on my High Sierra and it works fine

Comment: log show --predicate '(processImagePath contains "kernel") && (eventMessage contains "AirPort: Link Down")' --style syslog --last 1d

Comment: Ok, worked for me that time. Added the output

Comment: OK, so it turns off normally, so "something" is legitimately turning your WiFi off.

Comment: Is the country code stored in the hardware, because when it turns off, the country code in the hardware description changes to the X0. And all of the routers nearby are set to US, so it is not a country mismatch

Comment: XO is normal (baseline)  until it knows which country is it in (the IP number tells that)

Comment: So could the chip be turning itself off? I don't really see any possibility that the software is shutting it off when it does the same thing on a fresh install of mac

Comment: I do not think the chip would do that, but do believe it is some app doing it. You have to restart to restart the timer. Since I do not know what apps you have that might do that, you could look for it. Also I would double check your WiFi settings, the DHCP and click on the Renew DHCP lease.

Comment: If it even does it in recovery OS, I don't know what app would be doing it there.

Comment: I found this post too which is a similar issue https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169924/questionable-wi-fi-problem-on-mbp-how-to-analyse-it